# Always getting 404 Not Found response when trying to generate JWT token for XM Cloud via authentication clients

Tags: xm-cloud, automation, jwt-token

As per the documentation https://doc.sitecore.com/xmc/en/developers/xm-cloud/managing-xm-cloud-authentication-clients.html, I created a `Authentication Client` in `XM Cloud Deploy App` at the `Organization` level and i got the `Client ID` and `Client Secret`.

As a next step, i tried to get `JWT token` by following this document https://doc.sitecore.com/xmc/en/developers/xm-cloud/request-a-jwt-for-the-cm-instance-using-oauth.html, and run `curl` command like below.

```
curl --request POST --url "https://auth.sitecorecloud.io" --header "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" --data grant_type=client_credentials --data client_id=<clientid> --data client_secret=<clientsecret> --data audience=https://api.sitecorecloud.io
```

But i always get 404 Not Found response back.

Am i doing something wrong here?

Is there any other way to generate `JWT` token to trigger `XM Cloud` APIs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the response from Product team and they mentioned that the `url` we are passing in the request is not correct and Documentation has to be updated by Sitecore Docs team.

Here is the correct `curl` request.

```
curl --request POST --url "https://auth.sitecorecloud.io/oauth/token" --header "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" --data grant_type=client_credentials --data client_id=<clientid> --data client_secret=<clientsecret> --data audience=https://api.sitecorecloud.io
```

Woohoo, i tried with this, and it worked.